# Upper-bound on the ratio of gaussian pdf to cdf

Tags: inequality, normal-distribution, upper-lower-bounds

Suppose I have the following  function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$:
$$f(r) = (\gamma^2 -\epsilon^2) - 2 r^2 - r \frac{(\gamma -3\epsilon)\phi\left(\frac{\epsilon-\gamma}{r}\right)  - (\gamma+\epsilon)\phi\left(-\frac{\gamma+\epsilon}{r}\right) }{\Phi\left(\frac{\epsilon-\gamma}{r}\right)-\Phi\left(-\frac{\gamma+\epsilon}{r}\right)}$$

where $\phi$ and $\Phi$ are respectively the standard gaussian pdf and cdf, and  $\gamma>\epsilon>\frac{2}{3}\gamma>0$ are real-valued constants.

I am looking for a statement along the lines of:
if $r>g(\epsilon,\gamma)$ then $f(r)<0$.

[Here is a plot of how the function looks like for some fixed value of $\gamma$ and $\epsilon$.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vuMK.png)

Unfortunately, I was only able to show that
$f(r) \overset{r \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} \epsilon (\gamma - \frac{5}{3}\epsilon)$ which is a weaker statement. Any idea on how to tackle this problem is welcome (e.g. a tight upper-bound on the ratio of gaussian pdf to cdf).

(EDIT)
It might be helpful to know where does $f(r)$ comes from. I was originally interested in showing that the following quantity is negative:
$$(\gamma^2 -\epsilon^2) - (\gamma+\epsilon) \mathbb{E}[X] - 2\mathbb{E}[X^2 ] $$
where $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,r^2)$ is a gaussian r.v. truncated on $(\alpha,\beta)$ with $\alpha = -(\gamma+\epsilon)$, $\beta = -(\gamma-\epsilon)$. Plugging in the known moments of the truncated gaussian we get $f(r)$.

(UPDATE)
I was able to find a point $r_0=10(\gamma+\epsilon)$ such that $f(r_0) < 0$. Hence it would be enough to show that $f$ monotonically decreases for $r>r_0$ (numerically this seems to be the case).

Comment: Could you include some of the motivation for this question? Where did $f(r)$ come from? It may help people provide you with an answer.

Comment: $f(r)=\mathbb E[(\gamma^2 -\epsilon^2) - (\gamma+\epsilon)X - 2X^2] $ which is the expected value of a concave function so you can bound it with Jensens inequality (just flip the inequalities in the wiki article).

Comment: I don't see how bounding it with Jensen would make things easier as you still have to deal with the (nasty) expectation of truncated gaussian and its square

Comment: But it does give you a quadratic equation in $\Bbb EX$ which bounds $f$ from above. So if the result from Jensen is nonpositive then so must be $f$. You could try solving  for the zeros of that quadratic in terms of $\Bbb EX$ and see what that gives you. I haven't tried it myself so this is more of a passing comment.

Comment: That's a good point but unfortunately the upper-bound with Jensen is not tight enough to make this work